# How to add batch to a image using Tensorflow/numpy/keras?

Tags: image, numpy, tensorflow, keras, opencv, python

I have a image of shape (128,64,3). Now I need to add batch to this image to fit to a model. The output of my image should be (1,128,64,3) where 1 is the batch_size without effecting the image features.

Answer (score 2):

In order to feed the image in your model, you have to expand its dimensions. You can do that with:

```
image = np.random.rand(128, 64, 3)
# Image shape (128, 64, 3)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
# Image shape (1, 128, 64, 3)
```

---

However, if you want to plot the image, it has to have a 3D shape. In other words, the initial shape is just fine. However, if you already have a batch of images with the shape `(1, 128, 64, 3)`, then you can squeeze their shape like this:

```
img = np.squeeze(image)
# Image shape (128, 64, 3)
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(img)
```

Like this, plotting the image should be feasible. So, to summarize, the image input the model expects is different than the image input required if you want to plot an image. Namely, the model expects a 4D input `(batch_size, width, height, channels)` while matplotlib expects 3D input `(width, height, channels)`.

Comment: `img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)`

#Tried this but when trying with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(img)` getting this error.

TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Comment: If you want to do the tensor expansion outside of the graph definition then that is fine. I assumed that you want to do it inside the graph.

Comment: There is a model which I built but this image will not comply for this model. To make the image fit for the model, I need to make its shape into `(1,128,64,3)`

Comment: Even `tf.expand_dims(image,axis=0)` throws the same error when plotting.

Comment: After squeezing, it went back to (128,64,3)